# Notation for transitions in a continuous space.

Tags: graph-theory, notation, real-numbers

I am trying to solve a problem in continuous space $\Bbb{R}^2$, however, it was previously for non-directed graphs with edges and vertices.

Now, I am trying to translate this two concepts to the continuous space. I have stated that the vertices $V$ are now any point $v\in\Bbb{R}^2$  but for the edge set $E$ I don't know how to state that $\forall v$, its valid transitions are

> Any consecutive point in the state space

Is there any way I can express this? Or how can I translate the graph concepts of transitions in the real space?

Comment: Could you give some more details on the problem you are working on? It would help to understand your question.

Comment: It's based on a pathfinding problem. So in a grid world or discretized space it could be seen as a graph where the valid transitions in a cell (vertex) are those of the four or eight adjacent cells. But I am trying to solve this same problem for a continuous 2D space so I don't know how to write that the valid transitions at a given coordinate are any point at any direction